# Why can't I have the signin button work on my contact page?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

This is my `signin.js` file

```js
let mainBody = document.getElementById('body');
let signInBtn = document.getElementById('signin-btn');
 //creating login section
let loginBtnSection = document.createElement('section');
let studentLogin = document.createElement('div');
let writersLogin = document.createElement('div');
let createAccount = document.createElement("div");
let resetPassword = document.createElement("div");
if(this.loaded = true){
    signInBtn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        resetPage();
        loginChoicesPage();
        //riderecting to student login page
        studentLogin.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            resetLoginSection();
            studentLoginPage();
        });
        writersLogin.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            resetLoginSection();
            writersLoginPage();
        });
    });
    
}else{
    alert("The content is still loading");
};
```

```html
                <header class="header">
        <nav class="header-nav">
            <ul class="header-nav-menus">
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="../index.html" class="header-nav-menus-list-links">
                        <img src="../Images/reasearch-icons_logo-removebg-preview.png" alt="Research Icons Logo" class="header-Icons-logo">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="tel:+16122451224" class="header-nav-menus-list-links">
                        <i class="medium material-icons">call</i> <span>+1&nbsp;612 245 1224</span>
                    </a>
                    <a ></a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="../index.html#testimonials" class="header-nav-menus-list-links">
                        testimonials
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="#" class="header-nav-menus-list-links">
                        contacts
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="#" class="header-nav-menus-list-links">
                        prices
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="#" class="header-nav-menus-list-links">
                       blog
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="#" class="header-nav-menus-list-links nav-btns orderBtn">
                        Order Now
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-nav-menus-list">
                    <a href="#" class="header-nav-menus-list-links nav-btns" id="signin-btn">
                        Sign in
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I have this in my header section in both `index.html` and `contact. html`
When I click the signin button in `index.html` page, it works and navigate to another page but when I do the same in my `contact.html` page there is nothing going on. What could be the problem?
Put in mind that I am linking both html files to the JavaScript file. Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't assign event listeners inside a condition statement.

Comment: And especially not inside other event listeners

Comment: How should I have it when an event can only takes place in case a condition is met? for instance, operation on JS file can only be performed once the DOM in loaded? and what if another event can only occur on confdition that the first and initial event occurred?

Comment: To check whether DOM is loaded use the appropriate events(such as DOMContentLoaded) and inside the events assign the event listeners to your dom elements

Comment: Also how are you setting `this.loaded` value?

Comment: Also have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: I have just notice an error in if statement  = instead of ===